# Handling view logic in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I find that my `mapStateToProps` is increasing in complexity.

For example, across multiple connected components, I have been doing something like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    activeAsset: state.assets.byId[state.assets.activeAssetId].attributes
  }
}
```

**Problem #1:**
It is fairly obvious that the above code could be guarded with some conditionals since `activeAssetId` is not always set which will lead to the above throwing an error.

**Problem #2:** 
Suppose I wanted to get the current `activeAsset` in multiple components I now have to duplicate the code above.

I have heard of [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) but I am not entirely sure if this is the correct choice here since it seems to be used specifically with memoized functions.

Please excuse me if the answer is fairly obvious, I am fairly new to the redux ecosystem.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711359/changing-the-layout-of-a-component-depending-on-redux-state/40711713#40711713. It explains about separating business logic from views and also about using selectors for memoized and maintainable code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safe solution is to use a selector. Selectors are reusable functions that know the shape of the state in the store, and can produce derived data.

In your case, this can be your selector:

```
const getAssetAttributes = ({ assets }) =>  (assets.byId[state.assets.activeAssetId] && assets.byId[state.assets.activeAssetId].attributes) || null; // if the asset exists and has attributes return it, if not return null
```

Usage:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    activeAsset: getAssetAttributes(state)
  }
}
```

You can create selectors for every derived data, and store them in the relevant reducer's file, or in a seperate `selectors` file. [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) can help you with creating memoized standard selectors, but it's not required. Reselect selectors will returned the same data, if the parameters haven't changed, and this will prevent rerendering components needlessly.