# Is it good to pass all the redux states and actions to the child components via props?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been using Redux for a while from now. It feels really good.

The one pain point I have is, using `connect` in all the components to map `states` and `actions` to props.

For Example:

**index.jsx**

```
const uiStates = states => ({
  ui: states.reducer,
})

const uiActions = dispatch => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators({
    ...actions,
    ...APIs,
  }, dispatch),
})

@connect(uiStates, uiActions)
export default class Root extends Component {

}
```

Again, in the child components

**child.jsx**

```
const uiStates = states => ({
  ui: states.reducer,
})

const uiActions = dispatch => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators({
    ...actions,
    ...APIs,
  }, dispatch),
})

@connect(uiStates, uiActions)
export default class Child extends Component {

}
```

**Instead, can I pass the states and the actions as a prop from the `Root` toi the children?**

```
const uiStates = states => ({
  ui: states.reducer,
})

const uiActions = dispatch => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators({
    ...actions,
    ...APIs,
  }, dispatch),
})

@connect(uiStates, uiActions)
export default class Root extends Component {
   render(){
      return <Children {...this.props}/>
   }
}
```

I've tried it and it works great. But, is there any disadvantage in this method?
As an advantage, I see, I don't need to use `connect()` in all the componets.

Comment: no. you should only pass what is necessary. passing everything is a bad idea

Comment: @Mox If that's bad, what's the reason?  Even [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html) does it.

Comment: this is a general software engineering design principle. assuming that u r using a 3rd part component as child, what if the child actually modifies one of the prop without ur knowledge ?

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711359/changing-the-layout-of-a-component-depending-on-redux-state/40711713#40711713