# React Redux use HOC with connected component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am in the middle of my first React Native project. I would like to create a HOC that deals purely with syncing data from an api. This would then wrap all my other components.

If I am correct my `DataSync` component would enhance all other components by doing the following in the export statement:

`export default DataSync(SomeOtherComponent);`

The concept I am struggling with is that `SomeOtherComponent` also depends on the React Redux Connect method for retrieving other redux state. My question is how can I use both together? Something like this?

`export default DataSync(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SomeOtherComponent));`

I may have completely misunderstood the concept here so I would really appreciate some pointers

EDIT

To explain further:

My DataSync HOC would purely handle the syncing of data between the app and would be the top level component. It would need access to auth state and would set the data in Redux (in this case orders) for all other components.

Components nested within the DataSync HOC need access to the retrieved data, routes and they in turn create state (orders) that must be synced back to the server periodically.

Comment: yep that should work

Comment: maybe see also: [Connect with HOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59067643/redux-connect-w-hoc-typeerror-cannot-set-property-props-of-undefined)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

May be this is what you wanted:

**DataSync.js**

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DataSync);
```

**SomeOtherComponent.js**

```
export default DataSync(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SomeOtherComponent));
```

Use `connect` on your child components as well. Here is [WHY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40711713/5069226)

Answer (score 16):

Here is a simple example how it works

```
const AppWrapper = MainComponent =>
  class extends Component{
    componentWillmount(){
      this.props.fetchSomething()
    }
    componentDidUnmount(){
      this.props.push('/')
    }
    render(){
      return (
        <div>
          {this.props.fetchedUsers === 'undefined' ? 
            <div> Do something while users are not fetched </div> :
            <MainComponent {...this.props}/>}
        </div>
      )
    }
  }



const App = ({users}) => {
  // just example, you can do whatever you want
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(users)}</div>
};

// mapStateToProps will be in HOC -> Wrapper
// mapDispatchToProps will be in HOC -> Wrapper

/* you may use DataSync as you want*/
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppWrapper(App))
```

Useful [`HOC`](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.j8tcfuja4) link

Comment: Can you do it with a connect decorator instead of this syntax?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `connect` is also `HOC` and you can nest them arbitrary since a `HOC` returns a component.

`HOC(HOC(...(Component)...))` is OK.

---

However, I think what you might need is `connect(...)(DataSync(YourComponent))` instead of `DataSync(connect(...)(YourComponent))` so that `DataSync` could also access `state` / `props` if needed. It really depends on the use case.

Comment: thanks for the reply. So in essence which ever way I nest them determines the data the components inherit? This works just like any other component relationship?

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit more on your question? DataSync only inherits from connect if it is nested in connect. Every nested HOC1 inherits from every outer HOC2,3,4.. above it.

HOC3(HOC2(HOC1)) Now HOC1 inherits from HOC2 and HOC3.

Answer (score 5):

I had a very straight forward use case. I wanted to connect my HOC with redux store. In short I wanted to wrap my HOC with redux `connect` method.

```
// The HOC
const withMyHoc = (ReduxWrappedComponent) => props => <ReduxWrappedComponent {...props} />

// redux props
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({});

// This is important
export default (WrappedComponent) => 
connect(
  mapStateToProps, 
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withMyHoc(WrappedComponent));
```

There are two many answers in this thread. All of them helped me. Just putting down what actually worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I use and like the same approach that @The Reason mentioned. The only problem here is that if you map your actions you won't have dispatch() available.

The way how I managed to make it work in case someone is facing the same problem was the following.

```
const ConnectedComponentWithActions = connect(
  () => { return {}; },
  { myAction },
)(ViewComponent);

export default connect(
  state => state,
  null,
)(withPreFetch(firstLoadAction, ConnectedComponentWithActions));
```

Where `withPreFetch(firstLoadAction, ConnectedComponentWithActions)` is the HOC accepting an action to be dispatched.