# Using a HOC (higher order component) with React-Redux connect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, higher-order-components

I'm trying to get more comfortable with using higher order components so I'm working on refactoring an application. I have four different components that all reuse the same `fetchData` request, as well as error/loading conditionals. My plan is to take this reusable data and put it into a HOC. I've tried many different examples from StackOverflow, Reddit, Github, etc and none of them are working in my specific case.

Here's my HOC:

```
const WithDataRendering = WrappedComponent => props => {
class WithDataRenderingComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchData(url)
    }
    render() {
    if (this.props.hasErrored) {
        return (
        <p>
            Sorry! There was an error loading the items:{" "}
            {this.props.hasErrored.message}
        </p>
        )
    }

    if (this.props.isLoading) {
        return (
        <div>
            <Skeleton count={10} />
        </div>
        )
    }

    return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
    data: state.data,
    hasErrored: state.dataHasErrored,
    isLoading: state.dataIsLoading
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
    fetchData: url => dispatch(fetchData(url))
    }
}
return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
    WithDataRenderingComponent
)
}

export default WithDataRendering
```

And here's a component that I'm trying to wrap with the HOC:

```
export class AllData extends Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return (
        ...
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        data: state.data,
        hasErrored: state.dataHasErrored,
        isLoading: state.dataIsLoading
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchData: url => dispatch(fetchData(url))
    }
}

export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
    WithDataRendering(AllData)
)
```

I get three errors in the console:

`Warning: Component(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

`invariant.js:42 Uncaught Error: Component(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

`ReactDOMComponentTree.js:111 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$24sdkzrlvvz' of null`

A couple other techniques I tried are in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866308/react-redux-use-hoc-with-connected-component) and this [gist](https://gist.github.com/robinmonjo/2790fb319351843349cfec43213f4898). I've tried using `compose` and not using it, doesn't matter. I'm really at a loss here. Any ideas why this HOC isn't rendering properly?

Also, I'm not opposed to using `render props` as a solution if that fits better. I need to get more practice with both methods.

Comment: First thing I notice is that your HOC exports `WithGoDataRendering` which isn't defined anywhere (did you mean `WithDataRendering`?)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo while I was modifying my code. I've corrected it to reflect the proper names

Comment: You'll want to drop the `props =>` argument to `WithDataRendering`, and you currently `connect` both in the HOC and in the `compose` application (although that probably won't cause any errors). Just briefly glanced over the code though, so there might be some other issues.

Comment: You're right, `props =>` was the main issue. Will post more details later. Thank you.

Comment: Apologies for the off-topic question but what does this mean: `export class AllData extends Component<Props> {`? I am referring to the '<Props> alongside `Component` syntax.

Comment: <Props> is used for Flow type checking. I should have probably taken it off of this example since it isn't clarified elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to fix this by dropping the `props =>` argument as Oblosys suggested. I also reconfigured the `export` statement in AllData to be:

`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WithDataRendering(AllData))`

since I didn't really need to use `compose` there.