# Redux Connect w/ HOC - TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, higher-order-components

I'm building a quick authentication higher order component in Next.js and am getting some problems with the following code:

```js
import SignIn from "../components/sign-in";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const AuthenticationCheck = WrappedComponent => {
  const { isAuthenticated, ...rest } = props;
  const router = useRouter();
  const protectedPages = ["/colours", "/components"];
  const pageProtected = protectedPages.includes(router.pathname);

  return !isAuthenticated && pageProtected ? (
    <SignIn />
  ) : (
    <WrappedComponent {...rest} />
  );
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthenticationCheck);
```

If I change the code to remove redux & connect, it looks like this, and works perfectly.

```js
const AuthenticationCheck = WrappedComponent => {
  const { ...rest } = props;
  const router = useRouter();
  const protectedPages = ["/colours", "/components"];
  const pageProtected = protectedPages.includes(router.pathname);

  return pageProtected ? <SignIn /> : <WrappedComponent {...rest} />;
};

export default AuthenticationCheck;
```

I've been reading every SO, redux documentation etc for the last couple of hours, and I can't really find anything that matches what I'm doing, although I can't believe it's an uncommon use case.

Am I missing something obvious?

**Solution: (Thankyou Dima for your help!)**

So the final code that ended up working is:

```js
import SignIn from "../components/sign-in";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { compose } from "redux";

const AuthenticationCheck = WrappedComponent => {
  const authenticationCheck = props => {
    const { isAuthenticated, ...rest } = props;
    const router = useRouter();
    const protectedPages = ["/colours", "/components"];
    const pageProtected = protectedPages.includes(router.pathname);

    return !isAuthenticated && pageProtected ? (
      <SignIn />
    ) : (
      <WrappedComponent {...rest} />
    );
  };
  return authenticationCheck;
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
  };
}

export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps), AuthenticationCheck);
```

This works perfectly!

Comment: At which line you are getting the error ?

Comment: Feel free to accept answer if it helped. Thanks.

Comment: Mate, you're a champion... I'd tried a very very close version of your answer, but had missed the last comma in:

 "export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, {doSomething}),
  wrapComponent
)"

Now I can go to bed and sleep without thinking about this... thankyou! 

Comment: Thanks. Try eslint, it prevents this kind of errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`connect` expects to get React component as a last argument, but you are sending HOC instead. You need to put `connect` and wrapper inside `compose` function. See below

```js
import React from 'react'
import {compose} from 'redux'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {doSomething} from './actions'


const wrapComponent = Component => {
  const WrappedComponent = props => {
    return (
      <Component {...props} />
    )
  }
  return WrappedComponent
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    prop: state.prop,
  }
}

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, {doSomething}),
  wrapComponent
)
```

And the useit like this.

```js
import React from 'react'
import withWrapper from 'your/path'

const Component = props => 'Component'

export default withWrapper(Component)
```