# React states and mobx - antipattern?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, mobx

**Question:** Is it an anti pattern to both have mobx and react, then utilise both reacts component states, and the `@observer` `@observable` from mobx?

Since from what i can understand, mobx tries to replace the react states, or at least does something that is very similar.

Comment: The question is why would you do so? In one of my projects, I managed most the entire app's state using `MobX`, but I had a modal dialog component which needed to be a stateful component, so I managed that specific component's state with `setState()` because it seemed unnecessary to use `MobX` there ( but I might as well could have )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't call it an anti-pattern, but it defeats one of my favorite aspects of MobX. When using MobX, you are only ever dealing with props. I like this, because I never have to worry about whether a property lives in props or state. Since I started using MobX, I have never had a situation where I needed "state" local to a component. I find it best to keep all app state in stores, pass that state into top level components as props...

However, if you needed to have a "stateful" component using MobX, you could do something like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { action, observable }  from 'mobx';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

@observer
export default class User extends Component {
    @observable user = {
        firstName: 'john',
        lastName: 'lennon',
        status: 'alive'
    };

    @action updateUserStatus(newStatus) {
        this.user.status = newStatus
    }

    render() {
        const { firstName, lastName, status } = this;

        return (
            <p>{firstName} {lastName} - {status}</p>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using React components' internal state and MobX store together is not an anti-pattern in the broad sense. But consider the following points:

- Mixing component's internal state and a global state for the same purpose is not good. You will end up with conflicting states, you lose predictability and it becomes difficult to maintain.
- I believe anything that can be called as a [business logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40711713/5069226) should go in the global state.
- states that can be isolated to a single component can reside inside the component itself as far as it is not part of the business logic and our components should just observe them.
- Make your child components an `@observer`. Why? read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40711713/5069226) (replace `@connect` with `@observer`)
- MobX derivations are great substitutes for memoized custom getter/selector functions.