# React redux container with createselector that contains a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, es6-promise, reselect

I have a container that connects to the store, which is updated every second:

```
return ({ match, ui }, { matchId }) => ({
    value: match.getIn([matchId, 'masterCurrentTime'], 0), // about every second
    min: ui.get('seekStart'),
    max: ui.get('seekEnd'),
    highlightList: selectHighlights(matchId) // i only want to do this on first render
  });
```

However one of the properties (highlightList) does one of two things:

1) return a value from sessionStorage

or

2) downloads a file, saves it to sessionStorage and then returns it

Ofcourse i dont want to do this every second, only the first time.

I created a selector like this

```
const selectHighlights = createSelector(
    matchId => matchId,
    matchId => {
      if (matchId !== null) {
        getTimelineWithFilter(matchId, ['round_start'])
          .then(timeline => {
            console.log(timeline);
            return timeline;
          })
          .catch(error => {
            throw new Error('failed to load highlights', error);
          });
      }

      return null;
    }
  );
```

But it does not work, it is not rendered.
However if i do an alternative version where i store the result in a variable, and then query it, the thing works. It runs only once and performs as i like

```
// highlightList: currentTimeline === undefined ? loadHighlights(matchId) : currentTimeline,
```

I just want to learn how to do this the correct way, can anybody with knowledge about this give me some best practice tips?

Comment: you're msising the purpose of selectors when you put an API call inside `createSelector`; we lost our **memoized** code.

Comment: How would you go about doing it then, the examples i find, put the api calls in the "dumb" components componentWillMount() and then updates the state via that function, which triggers a render.
But that feels like im breaking the rule of it beeing a "dumb" component that only renders based on state/props from the container?

Comment: what you said is absolutely right, dumb component are really dumb, they are just pure functions. We don't make them do any thing other than just rendering something.

Comment: So, what is best practice when working with api calls, that will trigger a re-render of the component only when they recieve their result?

Comment: See whether this answer can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/40711713/5069226

Comment: I get the overall idea, i just need code examples of how people work with promises in react, do you know of anything like that?

Comment: sure, I will post a skeleton of the code structure to handle promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to handle promises in a React-Redux app?**

Let's say you have an **action creator** for fetching data from some API. You will dispatch the action from your component (on load / on click / on some other event).

```
export function loadData(key) {
  return {
    types: [LOAD_DATA, LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS, LOAD_DATA_FAIL]
    promise: () => fetch(...), // API call that returns a promise
    key,
  }
}
```

---

now create a [**middleware**](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) for promise based operations. Make sure you [`applyMiddleware`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html) when you create `store`.

> The most common use case for middleware is to support asynchronous
>   actions without much boilerplate code or a dependency on a library
>   like Rx. It does so by letting you dispatch async actions in addition
>   to normal actions.

```
export default function clientMiddleware() {
  return ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => (action) => {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
      return action(dispatch, getState);
    }

    const { promise, types, ...rest } = action;

    if (!promise) {
      return next(action);
    }

    const [REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE] = types;

    next({ ...rest, type: REQUEST });

    const actionPromise = promise();
    actionPromise
      .then(result => next({ ...rest, result, type: SUCCESS }))
      .catch(error => next({ ...rest, error, type: FAILURE }));

    return actionPromise;
  };
}
```

---

finally here is your **initialState**:

```
const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  isLoaded: false,
  data: {},
  error: null,
};
```

and  **reducers**:

```
case LOAD_DATA:
  return {
    ...state,
    isLoading: true
  };

case LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    isLoading: false,
    isLoaded: true,
    data: action.result,
  };

case LOAD_DATA_FAIL:
  return {
    ...state,
    isLoading: false,
    isLoaded: false,
    error: action.error
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. This is also terrifying, that all this is needed to do a simple api call...
I am still not convinced that React is something the world needs.

Comment: I concur that modern web apps are confounded by too much complexity. But I also should add, what we are doing here is just a one time job. We are essentially creating abstract methods to build our core so that our life will become easy in the future. Well, React is just the View layer of an MVC app, and we have  lot of options to implement our "M" and "C". This setup that I showed is a well accepted way of handling async data operations in Redux. In my opinion this would get a bit more straightforward and intuitive if we use [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx).