# Communicate between React components without a parent

Tags: reactjs

I was looking on how to communicate between 2 ReactJS components that doesn't share a parent, so it our just the root components on the page.

With some help of the internet, I've found our that Redux is the library that should be used, so that events are delegated to a store.

But where does this fit in the story if I want to create a simple component that's reusable, for example a button that's controllable from within other components?

Each button must have it's own unique events, but I don't see on how to do it practically.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you provide an example scenario where you'd want child components of different parentage to communicate with one another?  Or is it the case that you are trying to just make dumb/stateless/presentational components?

Comment: I just want to make presentational components, not complete application. For example, I want to create a component, let's say it's a button which have a few properties, such as "enabled". I want users to be install this component and expose an API for this command so it's "enabled" property can be controller from within any other components. Does that make sense to you? In JavaScript, you can reference a control by it's id and execute a method on it. I want something similar in ReactJS.

Comment: I think I understand. You do not need Redux to make presentational components, you can do this by passing the appropriate props to your presentational component. I'll add an example in an answer for you.

Comment: Thanks, would be great :-)

Comment: I think this is a broader topic, as we are talking about the entire Redux setup and example components, so that in the end we should be able to to justify why we really need a state management library like Redux. May be you can go through one of the Redux tutorials with example and comeback to ask about a specific part of a Redux application. We would be really glad to help in that case. Currently I see there is a lot of stories to be told, which will end up as a big article on Redux. :) See a good example tutorial here https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-redux/

Comment: Does that means that I need a state management library, like REDUX, to make a library of components that are reusable in other projects who's behaviour can be completely controlled by other third-party components? I do get the idea about Redux, but it doesn't fit in my logic of writing reusable components. If I write a component that should be reusable and implement redux, the event name for all the instances of the component would be the same, thus it makes no sense to me. Let's assume 3 buttons and a click on a button should disable another button. Doesn't seem to fit with redux.

Comment: Components should be pure. The shouldn't know who is going to use them. If we are dealing with presentational component, from which the logic of the application is abstracted, the components can stay dumb. ie they only need to expose some props, which can be data props, control flags, style properties, callback functions (which you invoke them based on events / state change etc). and so on

Comment: @free-soul Do you mean that a component should NEVER, EVER expose an API but rather let it's behaviour be controlled by states?

Comment: Exactly. I believe components should only represent the **View** in our MVC apps. Reusable components should never make API calls or do some specific business logic calculations. This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40711713/5069226 explains about structuring our components and abstracting logic from them (its is written for a Redux app).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Redux (or any state management library) is the way to go. In Redux, for instance, you've got two types of components: dumb components and high order components. High order components are used to connect with Redux state (see [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux)). So you can implement your button as a dumb component, which does not depend on Redux in any way, and connect to Redux in the root component

Comment: I'm fairly new to this, and I'm now I'm asking a great favor, but could you make a simple example. For example, 1 component, which is used twice on the same page, than can each be controlled individually from another component?