# Is it OK to put a container in a component in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm hacking with React/Redux and have been building lots of container and components.

However I recently encountered a design choice I made that made on of my Elements look like this:

[image]

My question is is this design OK? Basically I am struggling how to pass the `Redux Actions` down to the Button, since the button is a few levels deep. I could keep passing the actions down component to component from the `HeaderContainer`, but if the DOM got deeper it would just get worse and worse.

I feel like this design is WRONG since a presentational component is calling a container component.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, what I don't understand is, why do you need to connect to the store in the first place just to dispatch actions? You should connect to a store only if your component rendering needs to listen to changes in the store...

Comment: "presentational component is calling a container component". Dan Abramov says this is [fine](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.ssq4o7wml)

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

- First is to directly connect the button component to the store and let it be both container & presentational component. Simple and effective.

  `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ButtonComponent)`

  See an example from the creator of Redux [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/916) (the 4th post)
- Second is to create a container to wrap the button and let the button be only presentational - your current implementation. Very good layered architecture, but overengineered at this point for me.
- Third is to pass the action down from the `HeaderComponentContainer` to the `ButtonComponent`.

---

I would go for the third one if the button is no more than 2 levels deep, since you already connected your `HeaderComponentContainer` and as a parent it is its responsibility to determine what functionality its children should provide (they only present, right?).

PS. You can use [React's context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) to pass actions / properties arbitraly deep in the hierarchy without explicitely doing it for each component.

Comment: If I understand correct, the current implementation I have is basically the second one. Create a container component to wrap the button component. Sound about right? I just wanted to make sure it was a valid pattern.

Comment: I prefer using `@connect` on our presentational components. See [why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40711713/5069226).